# TensorBoard on Windows: 404 error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I've successfully installed and run TensorFlow on Windows 10 with Anaconda using pip on Python 3.5. After having run the project from here:

http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

I then run this command:

`tensorboard --logdir=./runs/1449760558/summaries/`

With no errors. However, when I go to load localhost:6000 I get the following:

```
GET http://localhost:6006/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js 
localhost/:24 GET http://localhost:6006/plottable/plottable.css 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/iron-icons/iron-icons.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/polymer/polymer.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-button/paper-button.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/numericjs_numeric_min_js/file/numeric.min.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/three_js_three_min_js/file/three.min.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/three_js_orbitcontrols_js/file/OrbitControls.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/weblas_weblas_js/file/weblas.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/lodash/lodash.min.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-slider/paper-slider.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-input/paper-input.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:126 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:126
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:126
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/d3/d3.js 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:1200 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1200
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1220
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1200
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1220
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-styles/paper-styles.html 
tf-tensorboard.html:1303 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1303
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1303
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-item/paper-item.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-menu/paper-menu.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:1389 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1389
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1389
tf-tensorboard.html:1515 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1515
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1515
tf-tensorboard.html:1614 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1614
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1614
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:1717 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1717
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1717
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/plottable/plottable.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/plottable/plottable.css 
tf-tensorboard.html:1754 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1754
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1754
tf-tensorboard.html:1932 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:1932
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:1932
tf-tensorboard.html:2482 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:2482
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:2482
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:2683 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:2683
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:2683
tf-tensorboard.html:2897 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:2897
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:2897
tf-tensorboard.html:3125 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:3125
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:3125
tf-tensorboard.html:3207 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:3207
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:3207
tf-tensorboard.html:3538 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SelectionBoxLayer' of undefined
    at Plottable (tf-tensorboard.html:3538)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:3540
Plottable @ tf-tensorboard.html:3538
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:3540
tf-tensorboard.html:4068 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'siSuffix' of undefined
    at VZ.ChartHelpers.VZ.ChartHelpers (tf-tensorboard.html:4068)
    at VZ (tf-tensorboard.html:4152)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4153
VZ.ChartHelpers.VZ.ChartHelpers @ tf-tensorboard.html:4068
VZ @ tf-tensorboard.html:4152
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4153
tf-tensorboard.html:4156 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4156
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4156
tf-tensorboard.html:4463 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4463
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4463
tf-tensorboard.html:4732 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'siSuffix' of undefined
    at VZ.ChartHelpers.VZ.ChartHelpers (tf-tensorboard.html:4732)
    at VZ (tf-tensorboard.html:4816)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4817
VZ.ChartHelpers.VZ.ChartHelpers @ tf-tensorboard.html:4732
VZ @ tf-tensorboard.html:4816
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4817
tf-tensorboard.html:4820 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4820
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4820
tf-tensorboard.html:4949 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:4949
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:4949
tf-tensorboard.html:5129 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:5129
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:5129
tf-tensorboard.html:5691 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:5691
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:5691
tf-tensorboard.html:5762 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:5762
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:5762
tf-tensorboard.html:5850 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:5850
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:5850
tf-tensorboard.html:5914 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:5914
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:5914
tf-tensorboard.html:6037 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:6037
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:6037
tf-tensorboard.html:6075 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:6075
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:6075
tf-tensorboard.html:6102 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:6102
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:6102
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/lodash/lodash.min.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/graphlib/dist/graphlib.core.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/dagre/dist/dagre.core.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/lodash/lodash.min.js 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/graphlib/dist/graphlib.core.js 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:8068 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at graph_1.layout.graph_1.layout (tf-tensorboard.html:8068)
    at tf.graph.tf.graph (tf-tensorboard.html:8655)
    at tf (tf-tensorboard.html:8656)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:8657
graph_1.layout.graph_1.layout @ tf-tensorboard.html:8068
tf.graph.tf.graph @ tf-tensorboard.html:8655
tf @ tf-tensorboard.html:8656
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:8657
tf-tensorboard.html:10474 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at scene.edge.scene.edge (tf-tensorboard.html:10474)
    at graph_1.scene.graph_1.scene (tf-tensorboard.html:10756)
    at tf.graph.tf.graph (tf-tensorboard.html:10757)
    at tf (tf-tensorboard.html:10758)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:10759
scene.edge.scene.edge @ tf-tensorboard.html:10474
graph_1.scene.graph_1.scene @ tf-tensorboard.html:10756
tf.graph.tf.graph @ tf-tensorboard.html:10757
tf @ tf-tensorboard.html:10758
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:10759
tf-tensorboard.html:13073 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:13073
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:13073
tf-tensorboard.html:13647 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:13647
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:13647
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:14087 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14087
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14087
tf-tensorboard.html:14370 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14370
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14562
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14370
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14562
tf-tensorboard.html:14621 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14621
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14673
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14621
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14673
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/iron-list/iron-list.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-item/all-imports.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:14959 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:14959
    at tf-tensorboard.html:15249
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:14959
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:15249
tf-tensorboard.html:15277 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:15277
    at tf-tensorboard.html:15316
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:15277
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:15316
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-progress/paper-progress.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:15435 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:15435
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:15435
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-tooltip/paper-tooltip.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:15965 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:15965
    at tf-tensorboard.html:16174
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:15965
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:16174
tf-tensorboard.html:16209 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:16209
    at tf-tensorboard.html:16243
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:16209
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:16243
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-input/paper-textarea.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-toast/paper-toast.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/iron-icons/image-icons.html 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-dialog-scrollable/paper-dialog-scrollable.html 
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:6006/paper-styles/typography.html 404 (Not Found)
tf-tensorboard.html:17889 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:17889
    at tf-tensorboard.html:17902
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:17889
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:17902
tf-tensorboard.html:18090 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at tf-tensorboard.html:18090
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:18090
tf-tensorboard.html:20231 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at Object.14../renderContext (tf-tensorboard.html:20231)
    at s (tf-tensorboard.html:18200)
    at e (tf-tensorboard.html:18200)
    at tf-tensorboard.html:18200
14../renderContext @ tf-tensorboard.html:20231
s @ tf-tensorboard.html:18200
e @ tf-tensorboard.html:18200
(anonymous) @ tf-tensorboard.html:18200
```

Any tips for a TensorFlow noobie on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The `0.12.0rc1` release with the fix to TensorBoard on Windows is now available from the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows) and [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow).

---

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5983) with the `0.12.0rc0` release of TensorFlow on Windows. It has been fixed in the repository, but we haven't yet made another official release that contains the fix. There are a few options right now:

1. Wait until the `0.12.0rc1` release is made, which should happen later this week.
2. Install a nightly build: [CPU](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/), [GPU](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=gpu,OS=windows/).
3. Build from source, by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/287db3a9b0701021f302e7bb58af5cf89fdcd424/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md).

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I'll try a nightly build! Thanks guys!